# dynamic css file won't load on web, works on xampp

Tags: php, css, xampp

This is my first question and I will try to do a good job.

I use a DSS file for my website in development as I want to "display:none" some divs if certain conditions are met (user is logged in -> no need for a register-form)

So my index.php head-tag for linking the stylesheet looks as follows:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.php" type="text/css">
```

the default.php CSS file has the following start:

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    header('Content-type: text/css');?>
```

On my local webserver (xampp on OS X) everything works just fine. 
But on the online server the css isn't applied. You can visit the broken website here:

hsturnierv2.pixelpioniere.net

It links the correct file, but the style is not applied.

EDIT:

Never underestimate the power of a linebreak. 
The php-tag in the CSS file did not start at line 1. Thank you!

Comment: check the css path once

Comment: @Deep Kakkar The path seems to be okay (Show source-code on the website - click on the link to the default.php and you will get there)

Comment: Check the MIME type the server is returning your css with. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Incorrect_MIME_Type_for_CSS_Files

Comment: You have used php code inside css file...remove it and add php code in php file

Comment: No, I used PHP code in a PHP file which dynamically generates the CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the MIME type the server is returning your css with. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Incorrect_MIME_Type_for_CSS_Files

Note: Even though you wil get it to work the way you want, you should double-check if the reduction in CSS file size makes up for the impossibility to cache the CSS client-side.

Apart from that, the actual problem is that you try to modify header information when the header has already been sent. This puts error message output on top of your css, invalidating it.

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /www/htdocs/w011c30e/hst/public_html/css/default.php:2) in <b>/www/htdocs/w011c30e/hst/public_html/css/default.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/htdocs/w011c30e/hst/public_html/css/default.php:2) in <b>/www/htdocs/w011c30e/hst/public_html/css/default.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. This website is in the early stages, so maybe I'll find another solution with javascript at some point. I just was not able to get my head around this problem here.

Comment: No problem, and +1 for playing Hearthstone :) I've also updated my answer.

Comment: I've just marked this as the correct answer - there was one linebreak on the first line before <?php... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your server is sending error message before the actual css:

http://hsturnierv2.pixelpioniere.net/css/default.php

Disable error displaying, or fix the issue with headers.

Comment: I just put an "@” in front of the php functions and there are no more errors. Still no style :(

Comment: It's enough to disable *warning* displaying. No errors here.

Comment: Yep it works because I found out that the css file did not start at line 1. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

I go to your CSS link and get Warning:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent
```

It means that your script file send the output for client before session_start().

1. Make sure there is absolutely no whitespace or another characters before `<?php`
2. If that fails, try commenting out the session_start() as one of your includes might already be starting the session, like so:  `/**session_start(); **/`

Answer (score -2):

You've inserted PHP code into your CSS file, that is wrong, please remove it.

```
<?php 
session_start();
header('Content-type: text/css');?>
```

This is for your PHP file.

Comment: That's okay: `href="css/default.php"`. The PHP file returns CSS.

Comment: Even if that works, why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: But that's the only way I know to dynamically adjust my css using php. And the local xampp does it just fine? "This is for your PHP file." - which one? My stylesheet already is a PHP file with an inserted header.

Comment: To have dynamically generated CSS files, depending on PHP logic.

Comment: @odedta As stated in my question: I want to display:none; some divs depending on certain $_SESSION variables. This is the only way to do this I guess.

Comment: Okay then some server misconfiguration is causing this since you say it works with xampp... check your php.ini ? or try `ob_start();`